# Child process won't run after install (using Setup project)

Tags: c#, forms, process, setup-project

I'm currently developping a solution that contains 2 projects. The "main" one is launching the second one as a sub process using this code :

```
monitorProcess = new Process();
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
monitorProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(path, @"Monitor.exe");
monitorProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
monitorProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
monitorProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
monitorProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
monitorProcess.OutputDataReceived += Process_OutputDataReceived;

monitorProcess.Start();

monitorProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

The main application is a classic Windows Form, and the second one is a "Keylogger" based on [this](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-simple-hidden-console-keylogger-c-sharp-0132757/) example.

Everything works fine in development phase, but as soon as I'm packaging all of this in a Setup installer (Using Setup project from Visual Studio), the second process is not launched, without any errors showing...

Any idea what I could be missing ? Could it be something related to the Keylogger not being authorized ? If I launch it as a standalone it works perfectly...

Comment: Maybe `Monitor.exe` has some dependencies (some DLL's are missing)?

Comment: No dependencies missing since I can easily launch "monitor.exe" as a standalone from a cmd shell